# Importing dataset with badly organized headers

Tags: r

I have [this dataset](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/data.csv) from the European Central Bank, but it is not coded in suitable way for importing to R:

When trying to import using read.csv I get the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : 
  more columns than column names
```

I'm wondering what the right method of correcting this is?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `skip` argument to not read in the first few lines, which are causing your problems:

```
europeanCB <- read.csv("path/to/data.csv", skip = 4)
```

You'll probably still want to do a little bit of cleaning up on the column names though. Currently, they look like this:

```
head(names(europeanCB))
[1] "Period.Unit."          "X.Australian.dollar.." "X.Bulgarian.lev.."  
[4] "X.Brazilian.real.."    "X.Canadian.dollar.."   "X.Swiss.franc.."
```

A little bit of `gsub()` would solve that problem quickly:

```
names(y) <- gsub("X\\.|\\.$|\\.\\.$", "", names(y))
head(names(y))
[1] "Period.Unit"       "Australian.dollar" "Bulgarian.lev"   "Brazilian.real"   
[5] "Canadian.dollar"   "Swiss.franc"
```